# Request fails while having a bearer token in the header of the request

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, bearer-token

I'm facing a problem with fetch API while sending a bearer token in the request header. The problem is that the request fails while having this token in the header but everything works fine when there is no token in the header and the request can fetch. Any idea of how to solve this issue? I really appreciate any help.

```
const url = "https://something.com"
const token = "something";
const options = {
headers: {
  Accept: "application/json",
  Authorization: "Bearer " + token
 }
};
fetch(url, options)
 .then((res) => {
 if (res.ok) {
   return res.json();
 } else {
   throw Error("Error!");
 }
})
.then((data) => {
        ...
 })
.catch((error) => {
        ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Accept part:

Edit:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) header.

When Site A tries to fetch content from Site B, Site B can send an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to tell the browser that the content of this page is accessible to certain origins. (An origin is a domain, plus a scheme and port number.) By default, Site B's pages are not accessible to any other origin; using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header opens a door for cross-origin access by specific requesting origins.

For each resource/page that Site B wants to make accessible to Site A, Site B should serve its pages with the response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com
```

Found it on another post, may help too.

```
 const options = {
    headers: {
      Content-Type: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` //Change it too
    }
 };
```

Related to the token, one way to pass it would be like this:

```
 const options = {
    headers: {
      //Something else...

      Authorization: `Bearer ${yourToken}`
    }
 };
```